# Screen turns off immediately after X starts

Tags: xorg, screen, hdmi

Yesterday I disconnected my HDMI monitor, and connected to another monitor while the system was running. The resolution was now too high for the new monitor (1280x720 monitor was showing the 1920x1080 display ok but scaled down and everything was blurry) so I went to change the resolution. The monitor settings dialog was in a strange state where the "Turn on" checkbox was unchecked, and I could not edit it, like in this screenshot http://www.iforce2d.net/monitorSettingsDialog.png (I took this screenshot later and edited a little to show what I mean).

[image]

When I clicked apply there was a warning saying that checkbox should not be left empty, but since it was grayed out I couldn't change it, and I figured if it caused a problem I could always just revert it in some settings file.

After applying the screen resolution in this dialog, nothing happened, so I rebooted to see if anything would change. Now when I reboot, for a brief moment  (about half a second) the desktop shows and I can move the mouse cursor, and then the monitor turns off and says 'no HDMI signal'. I can use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to log in and look at logs etc.

http://www.iforce2d.net/Xorg.0.log.txt

Is there some file I can edit to revert that checkbox?

If it makes any difference, this is Ubuntu 14.04 running on an Odroid-U3, an arm processor. This version of Ubuntu has been modified slightly to add driver support for this board, but I suspect this issue could be a generic Ubuntu thing.

Comment: I think "turn on" doesn't mean "use this monitor". I think it means "if this monitor is to be used, power it on if it's powered off". That is a common HDMI feature. The fact that it is greyed out, however, means that the monitor may not have that feature, or the feature is disabled in the monitor.

Comment: Could you please give us some more info like: `lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release`? and post your `monitors.xml` to http://paste.ubuntu.com ?